# Having a form for sending emails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to rails and was wondering if there was a way to make a form in the views folder so that I can send an email.
The form would need an input for:
The email address; the  subject; message.

Then basically you press send and it sends the email

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using :

```
 Mailer Form

<%= form_tag '/path' do%>
Email : </br><%= text_field_tag 'email', ''%></br>
subject: </br><%= text_field_tag 'subject', ''%></br>
Body:<%= text_area_tag 'body', ''%>
<%= submit_tag "submit",:value => "submit"%>
<%end%>

For Controller

 def path 
   data = params[:body]
   subject=params[:subject]
   user = params[:email]
   Mailer.mail_method(data,user,subject).deliver
 end

For Mailer

  def mail_method(data,email,subject)
    @body=data
    mail(to: email, subject: subject)
  end
```

Mailer view

```
  <%=@body%>
```

Comment: this looks nice and tidy, but where does the "For Mailer" bit go?

Comment: its for the mailer from which you are sending the mail. Example class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

Comment: So have it and when i press submit I get a `No route matches [POST] "/path"` error, do i need something to put into routes?

Comment: yes you need to define a post route for your path action.

Comment: where do you put your email address ?

Comment: you did not address routes in your answer

Answer (score 1):

The form would just be your basic Rails view and controller action, for sending the email itself check out [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

However if you're looking for something really basic, just to send email from a form,  There's a lot of ready-made solutions that don't involve rolling your own with Rails.  I use [Formspree](https://formspree.io/).

Comment: I think i'm being a bit thick here, but i can't worked out how where i put my form

Comment: Rails Mailer is a little strange, particularly if you're new to Rails.  Its completely concerned with the sending of email and decoupled from everything else.  So your form will be just another view, and its submit action will go to just another controller action.

However, once in the controller that's where you fire off the Action Mailer method.  Check the first link there to the Rails Guide, it really kind of walks you through what to do.

Comment: Check www.enformed.io, has a couple of interesting features, like setting the redirect after submiting, and email customization.